# How to show the following sets are Homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

How to show that the set $X_1 = \{(x,y) \in R^2\,:\,(x+y) \geq 0\text{ and }{(xy) = 0}\}$
and $X_2 = \{(x,y) \in R^2\, :\, (x+y) \geq 0\text{ and }{(xy) = 1}\}$
are homeomorphic?

I know they are homeomorphic. But I can not prove that. Any hint will be highly appreciated. I drew two graphs. But I am still clueless.

Comment: yesss..100%.............................

Comment: because answer key reads so.

Comment: https://www.imsc.res.in/~office/nbhm/qp/nbhmra06.pdf and https://www.imsc.res.in/~office/nbhm/qp/nbhmra06key.pdf

Comment: please check the question number 3.6. This is the most prestigious phd screening test in India. I don't think they would give wrong answer.

Comment: In each case show that $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$ is a homeomorphism to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I was wrong. Comments deleted.

Comment: I understood...@LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 1):

Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&X_2&\longrightarrow&X_1\\&\left(x,\frac1x\right)&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\left(0,\frac1x-x\right)&\text{ if }x\leqslant1\\\left(x-\frac1x,0\right)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.